# MYSQL - How to use LIKE operator in joined table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search some terms in related table and get filtered results.

For this purpose I used below sql, it didn't throw any error but it's not return any result either

```
SELECT *
FROM ads ad
JOIN contents c ON c.ad_id = ad.id 
    AND (c.title LIKE '%iphone%' OR c.content LIKE '%iphone%')
WHERE ad.type = "phone"
ORDER BY ad.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

How do I use LIKE operator in joined table, is my approach wrong? If is what kind of adjustment that I can do for it ?

Comment: Seems good to go.

Comment: Are you sure the `ad.type = "phone"` not `%phone%`. Or maybe leading/trailing whitespace in data will also not return any result.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan but it returns empty result..

Comment: Try to use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN only.

Comment: Can you post data sample?

Comment: Looks good. Can you point out what's your expected result you are not getting? Yes, please add the sample data.

Comment: I would put the `LIKE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause, but with an `INNER` join like you have it should give you the same results.  The SQL is correct (assuming that is what you want for your conditions).  It must be that your data does not match all the conditions.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I solve the problem. It because my search term is iphone, but in the titles, it's` Iphone`. Mysql couldn't find record it search case sensitively

Comment: @TeomanTıngır can you share schema ?